# No temperature info?

Tags: temperature

How can I see a read out of my CPU or in general how much my laptop is overheating? I tried this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvO35KYi4_U) where all the temperature info is shown when you type "sensors", but I'm not getting anything -
[image]

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and I don't know anything about it so what can be the problem? I also noticed I can't run new programs like Blender (donloaded as as ZIP so it doesn't require instalation). How can I check if I have a limited version of the OS because I believe it shouldn't work like this. Here's the program folder -
[image]

I'm just plain confused, please help!

Comment: 1. The error message in your first screenshot tells you exactly what to do: Install *lm-sensors*. 2. Blender is available at the official repositories and it can and should be installed that way.

Comment: There is no limited version of Ubuntu, it is free. If you just read the output in your first screen shot it says run `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`.

Comment: @Mark Kirby Thanks :). The video didn't show I need a new program (perhaps in the description). I still don't know about programs like Blender, but thet should be another post I guess. I think you mean it should be preinstalled, but I need the latest version

Comment: Just install blender with `sudo apt-get install blender` if you do it any other way, you will need to fix things like dependencies and it is not worth the effort.

Comment: @Mark Kirby Yeah, I heard  ubuntu programs should be installed through the Terminal, I'm learning programming at the moment. Thanks

Comment: If you are not to comfortable with terminal, `ubuntu-software` is a GUI for it and is pre installed.

Comment: @Vladimir sing commands in terminal isn't "programming".

Comment: @CelticWarrior Yeah, I know, but it's kinda sinonymous 'cause you type in a code to get things done (just to mention I deleted the last comment if it still shows on your screen)

Answer (score 3):

You don't have installed sensors utility. You can install it by

```
sudo apt-get install lm-sensors
```

as stated on first screenshot.

As for `Blender`, it is in the repository’s, just run

```
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :). The video didn't show I need a new program (perhaps in the description). I still don't know about programs like Blender, but thet should be another post I guess. I think you mean it should be preinstalled, but I need the latest version.